# 'Query was empty' error when pushing form data to Database PHP, MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

The code I am using (below) doesn't work for some reason, I check everything matches in the html form - I just can't figure this out.

Could I be getting the error because something that is wrong on the HTML side? I'm using the jQuery form validator (this works fine) could this cause problems? 
http://jqueryvalidation.org/

```
<?php

$host="localhost"; // Host name 
$username="USERNAME"; // Mysql username 
$password="PASSWORD"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="DBNAME"; // Database name 
$tbl_name="Persons"; // Table name 

// Connect to server and select database.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// Get values from form 
$fname=$_POST['fname'];
$lname=$_POST['lname'];
$company=$_POST['company'];
$email=$_POST['email'];
$registered=$_POST['registered'];
$percentage=$_POST['percentage'];
$products=$_POST['products'];
$prize=$_POST['prize'];
$terms=$_POST['terms'];
$newsletter=$_POST['newsletter'];


// Insert data into mysql 
$sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name(FirstName, LastNname, Company, EmailAddress, Registered, PercentOfBusiness, ProductsSold, WhichPrize, Newsletter)VALUES('$fname', '$lname', '$company', '$email', '$registered', '$percentage', '$products', '$prize', '$terms', '$newsletter')";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// if successfully insert data into database, displays message "Successful". 
if($result){
echo "Successful";
echo "<BR>";
echo "<a href='insert.php'>Back to main page</a>";
}

else {
echo "ERROR";
}
?> 

<?php
$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
?>

<?php 
// close connection 
mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: easiest way to debug is to echo out the value of $sql and see what the database is seeing.

Comment: What does the **jQuery** portion of your code look like?

Comment: `$result=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error()."<br />$sql");`

Comment: Sometimes, I wish there were a means to delete every sh*t php/mysql tutorial on the web. Can anyone from Google amend search engine results? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: use `isset()` to check whether values set or not

Comment: @Ricky - can you please post the link of the tutorial or whatever you read that told you to create such code? It's just for personal curiosity purposes

Comment: Sure I got it here: http://www.phpeasystep.com/mysql/5.html

Answer (score -1):

Your getting the error on

```
 <?php
  $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
 ?>
```

Which is executed later down your script and `$query` is not set. Your real insert is way up above.

```
$sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name(FirstName, LastNname, Company, EmailAddress, Registered, PercentOfBusiness, ProductsSold, WhichPrize, Newsletter)VALUES('$fname', '$lname', '$company', '$email', '$registered', '$percentage', '$products', '$prize', '$terms', '$newsletter')";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
```

You should also change that to `$result=mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());`

and see if there is errors on the actual insert. remove the secondary query execution.

Comment: Thanks for the help, changed the line you mentions now I get the error: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Comment: you have 9 columns in your insert and 10 items in your values side I believe , '$terms' is the offending item.  Either remove that value from the values side or add a terms column into the left side.

Answer (score -1):

```
$sql="INSERT INTO $tbl_name VALUES(FirstName, LastNname, Company, EmailAddress, Registered, PercentOfBusiness, ProductsSold, WhichPrize, Newsletter)VALUES('$fname', '$lname', '$company', '$email', '$registered', '$percentage', '$products', '$prize', '$terms', '$newsletter')";
$result=mysql_query($sql);
```